# MOXy JAXB breaks on XmlIDREF to type that has an enum attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I have set up a minimal working example of the problem I have. These are the `JAXB` classes.

**moxytest/A.java**

```
package moxytest;
@XmlRootElement
public class A {

    @XmlElement(name = "b")
    public List<B> bs;

    @XmlElement(name = "c")
    public List<C> cs;
}
```

**moxytest/B.java**

```
package moxytest;    
public class B {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    public String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    public EnumD md;
}
```

**moxytest/C.java**

```
package moxytest;
public class C {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlIDREF
    public B b;
}
```

**moxytest/EnumD.java**

```
package moxytest;
@XmlEnum
public enum EnumD {

    VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3
}
```

**Example input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<a>
    <b id="b1" md="VALUE1"/>
    <b id="b2" md="VALUE2"/>
    <b id="b3" md="VALUE3"/>
    <c b="b2"/>
    <c b="b1"/>
    <c b="b3"/>
</a>
```

So `C` elements are referencing `B` elements by id, and `B` elements have an Enum attribute.

This line of Java code

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);
```

Produces an exception with the following message:

> The @XmlAttribute property b in type moxytest.C must reference a type that maps to text in XML.  moxytest.B cannot be mapped to a text value.

I have been debugging and reading some lines of `MOXy` source code. That is how I was able to set up this minimal example. The `JDK` implementation works fine.

**EDIT:**

I am using EclipseLink 2.6.0 (thanks Santhosh Kumar Tekuri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code with following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

i placed jaxb.properties in same package where model classes exist. this file contains:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

and it works fine. below is my unmarshalling code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

make sure you are using same moxy version I am using.

Comment: I was using version 2.6.0, I will check with 2.5.0

Comment: Ive checked with 2.5.0 and it works. Looks like the new code for validating properties has bugs. Ive tried MOXy on the bigger project (>50 jaxb classes). The oroginal issue is gone with 2.5.0 but now there is issue when unmarshalling. It produces an NPE somewhere deep only when running, not when debugging, so Ive reverted back to JDK jaxb.